# Extract data from BigQuery to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, google-bigquery

I am looking for ways to extract the data from BigQuery and load into Cassandra. I believe Talend has the connectors to extract data from BigQuery and load data to Cassandra. Is there any other tools that can do this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you looking for tools or you want to build it yourself using API?

Comment: @Pentium10, I am looking for tools